# Select all text in element in Internet Explorer 11 with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Selecting all text in an element with Selenium WebDriver normally works like this.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
element.click();
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
```

For internet explorer 11 I set these capabilities.

```
capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capability.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
capability.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);
capability.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
```

Selecting all text then, does not work. I use Selenium WebDriver 2.48.2 and IEdriverServer 2.48.0.

My quick and dirty solution is to use a robot in the WebDriverEventListener.

```
Robot r = null;
try {
    r = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
@Override
public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    r.setAutoDelay(30);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
}
...
@Override
public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
}
```

This works. But who knows a cleaner, less contrived solution?