# Selenium Internet Explorer click button

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

I have a problem. I want to click for button and open link in new tab. This my code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(this.driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(myButton).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

But link is opened on current tab, not new tab.
This is bug of that?

P.S. on chrome and firefox this code work very well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because i need open new tab when i click to button and this problem reproduce only on internet explorer driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to open a new window before clicking the link :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
// open a new window
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open(window.location.href, '_blank');");
// set the context to the new window
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1]);
// click the link
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Stack Overflow")).click();
```

Another solution would be to set the target attribute on the targeted element:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Stack Overflow"));
// set the target _blank on the link
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].target='_blank';", element);
// click the link
element.click();
// set the context to the new window
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The first solution is works, and i will use it. But i can't understand, why internet explorer driver not implement clicks with modifiers

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine but the IEDriver is not quite as good as the ones for FireFox and Chrome. I had similar issues, as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198934/select-all-text-in-element-in-internet-explorer-11-with-selenium-webdriver). I ended up solving my issues with the `java.awt.Robot`. In your case that would mean you'd need an IE-specific method for opening in new tab.

```
Robot r = null;
try {
    r = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
r.setAutoDelay(30);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

//then click the button

r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

It's not elegant but it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i think this solution will workaround for me. But this solution is works